# Bat File to close Program after 5 minutes of inactivity

Tags: batch-file

First off, some background: I'm a student on co-op at an engineering firm, and I need to write a .bat file to close a scanning program after 5 minutes of not being use. the scanner is on a local network, and won't let anyone open the program to scan anything if someone else is using it.

So my question is whether or not there is a .bat command that can check inactivity, like measure how long it's been since someone has clicked a button, and after 5 minutes of nothing, close the program.

I've made a file that will open the program, and close it after a 5 minute timer, which will suffice for now, but I want to try to make it better. Any advice would be great! Thanks!

```
@echo off
cd "C:\WINDOWS\twain_32\escndv"
start escndv.exe >NUL

PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 300000 >NUL

Taskkill /im escndv.exe >NUL

echo Epson GT-20000 has been terminated due to inactivity

PAUSE
```

I have minimal experience with .bat files, so what I have is from a couple hours looking around on Google.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
schtasks /create /sc ONIDLE /i 5 /tn scanner /tr closescanner.bat
```

This will create a scheduled task to run `closescanner.bat` when the pc has been idle for 5 minutes.

Just create a separate batch file called `closescanner.bat` with `Taskkill /im escndv.exe >NUL` inside to close the app when no-one has touched the pc for 5mins.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please recommend some Microsoft command line god level book? i really need like those command line arguments for one big project, i need real paper old school books, do you know any books which list all those command line arguments to give verbose knowledge on windows command line only?